# Why is it not almost sure convergence?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of RV defined by

$P\{X_n=0\}=1-1/n$ and $P\{X_n=1\}=1/n, n=0,1,\dots$

Here can we find a distribution $X$ such that $\lim{X_n \to (a.s) X}$?

My approach: For $X=0$ we could say $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ but I am not able to understand why/why not this distribution does not converge almost sure? I know the definition of almost sure convergence says for all $w$, $\{P{w | \lim{X_n(w) \to X(w)}}=1\}$ but here maybe (not sure) since we don't know the w dependence we say no conclusion. But the answer says no such distribution exists. I am confused. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_n \to 0$ in probability and  $\sum_n P(X_n=1)=\infty$ If $X_n$'s are independent it follows that $X_n$ does not converge almost surely. However, it is possible for $X_n$ to converge to $0$ almost surely if we allow the variables to be dependent. Example: On $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure take $X_n=I_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$.